# How to pass a file path to subprocess in python

Tags: python

I used PyInstaller to pack my app into a single app.exe file.

App.exe contains

- App.py
- Telegram.py

And there's config.json located in the same folder as App.exe (easier to modify)

App.py will use subprocess.Popen to call Telegram.py

Since App.py is the main app, it can easily located the config.json

`config_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.executable)), 'config.json')`

```
script_name = "TelegramPage4.py"
script_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), script_name)
subprocess.Popen(["python", script_path])
```

but the Telegram.py couldn't locate it, because it was packed, it will either find in the MEIPASS or Python.exe.

Right now in Telegram.py it is locating the config_path the same way of App.py as above (I know it's not working)

How can I pass the config_path to the Telegram.py?

I tried using argparse but never worked

Comment: "Packed" meaning part of the executable? If you haven't copied the content to a distinct file, then there doesn't exist any path that refers to it. You can of course write code to create and populate a temporary file, or use something like a named pipe. In general, though, building a single executable is a bad idea and best avoided in the first place; it makes your programs slower to start up and creates complications like the one you're facing now.

Comment: Anyhow, why did you write telegram.py to need a config file (instead of being able to be passed a native data structure with everything needed, or having defaults that match your needs when no file is provided) in the first place? It's inside your control to change that; the easy answer is to suggest that you do so.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes "packed" means I grab all the python scripts into a single .exe file. I do think about copying all the values from config file to a temporary file but I'm afraid that I wont handle deleting it properly because my script quits quite often

Comment: Pyinstaller and similar tools also provide facilities for storing "resources" in the executable; see the documentation for whichever such tool you used here.

Comment: If you're on any reasonable operating system -- the only unreasonable one I know of is Windows -- you can delete the temporary file while it's still in use and the storage won't be deallocated until your program exits; temporary files managed that way are cleaned up automatically.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I want to read the port number inside config.json and send a message by Telegram.py to know which port is running properly and which is not

Comment: Why do you need a JSON file for that? If it's built into your executable it can't be changed, so why wouldn't you just make it code? And if you need to change it and have those changes be saved across invocations then you can't build it into the executable at all.

Comment: No it's not fixed number inside the executable, I made it that way so I can just edit the config.json and multiply it into hundreds of concurrent executables with different ports

Comment: How is that different from editing a config.py that you build into hundreds of executables?

Comment: (mind, using pyinstaller for anything you're running lots of concurrent copies of is a horrible idea on the first place; it makes your Python programs much less memory-efficient than they would be with a regular interpreter installation where all the concurrent copies of the interpreter can have the same disk blocks mapped into their virtual memory space)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for your recommendation, I might try a better approach to my use case. And for the problem I posted, I found out why, because I didn't declare 'type=str'. I started to think that I'm sleep deprived

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself

In the main application:

`config_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.executable)), 'config.json')`

```
script_name = "TelegramPage4.py"
script_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), script_name)
subprocess.Popen(["python", script_path, config_path])
```

In the sub-application

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('config_path', type=str, help='Path to the configuration file')
args = parser.parse_args()

# See the config path
print(args.config_path)

config_path = args.config_path
```

It couldn't pass the config path properly in the first place because I didn't use `type=str`